# Repeatedly prompt user until resolved using nodeJS async-await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I try repeteadly asking question to user until they gave the correct answer using this code.

The problem is, it won't resolve if the user doesn't gave the right answer at the first time.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

function promptAge() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        rl.question('How old are you? ', function(answer) {
            age = parseInt(answer);
            if (age > 0) {
                resolve(age);
            } else {
                promptAge();
            }
        });
    });
}

(async function start() {
    var userAge =  await promptAge();
    console.log('USER AGE: ' + userAge);
    process.exit();
})();
```

Here are the terminal outputs for each condition:

When user gave the right answer the first time it was fine ...

```
How old are you? 14
USER AGE: 14
```

When user gave the wrong answer it was stuck (won't resolve and process won't exit) ...

```
How old are you? asd
How old are you? 12
_
```

When user doesn't gave any answer it was also stuck ...

```
How old are you? 
How old are you? 
How old are you? 12
_
```

Could anyone explain what happened or give me any reference to an article/video that explain this nature?

Btw, i try to do this using async/await for learning purpose (trying to learn how to do things asynchronously). I already tried this without async/await (promptAge() doesn't return any promise) and it was okay.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing to do with `parseInt()` although skellertor is advising good practice.

The problem is that you're generating a new Promise every time `promptAge()` is called - but the **original** caller i.e. `start()` only has visibility of the first Promise. If you enter a bad input, `promptAge()` generates a new Promise (inside a never-resolved Promise) and your success code will never run.

To fix this, only generate one Promise. There are more elegant ways to do this but for clarity, and to avoid hacking the code into something unrecognisable...

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

// the only changes are in promptAge()
// an internal function executes the asking, without generating a new Promise
function promptAge() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var ask = function() {
      rl.question('How old are you? ', function(answer) {
        age = parseInt(answer);
        if (age > 0) {
          // internal ask() function still has access to resolve() from parent scope
          resolve(age, reject);
        } else {
          // calling ask again won't create a new Promise - only one is ever created and only resolves on success
          ask();
        }
      });
    };
    ask();
  });
}

(async function start() {
    var userAge =  await promptAge();
    console.log('USER AGE: ' + userAge);
    process.exit();
})();
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Thank you!

Is the more elegant solution to built an `ask()` function outside and passing `resolve` as an argument?

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Tried to avoid radically changing your code so you could understand the concept -but it's pretty good and was only missing that one crucial thing. The answer to your follow-up question is one of style -passing `resolve()` around as an argument would work, but not good practice. This is an example of closure, where children retain access to parent values and IMHO it's the better pattern, and clearer, being self-contained.

Comment: P.S. if you're using shiny `async / await` then you may as well hop over to using ES6 now, with `const` and `let` instead of `var` plus a load of other goodies which you'll wonder how you ever did without!

Comment: I'm still in a bootcamp (3rd week) and ES6 is on the 6th week. lol.

This code is part of this week's weekly project, but since i found that my code looks too dirty calling functions here and there and inside another functions, i tried to make it looks nicer and struggling with setTimeout(), async loop, and async/await in the past few days. This is the [crap](https://github.com/sirnobrain/firstJSapp/blob/master/myGame.js) that i'm talking about xD

Comment: Don't underestimate what you're building there - you'll learn loads working towards something real, and fixing real-world problems no matter how trivial it seems. Far better than tutorials!

To get all this stuff, focus on understanding callbacks before you go into Promises and async/await. Callbacks are the essence of async programming, and spending a few hours to really get to grips with them will pay huge dividends. This is node-oriented but a good read (from 3rd para.) https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and advice. I'll take a look into that link :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has to do with your `parseInt()` function.  In both cases you are passing a non-Number value. First check if it is a number before parsing it into an int.

Comment: I tried drjimmie1976 solution and he is right.
But thank you for your advice to check a number first before parsing an int! Really good advice :)